# How to replace figure with placeholder or certain image in word document using apache poi,?

Tags: java, apache-poi, placeholder

Let's assume i have a word document, with this body.
[Word document before replacing images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQhNR.png)

```
    private void findImages(XWPFParagraph p) {
    for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
        for (XWPFPicture pic : r.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
            XWPFPicture picture = pic;
                XWPFPictureData source = picture.getPictureData();
                BufferedImage qrCodeImage = printVersionService.generateQRCodeImage("JASAW EMA WWS");
                File imageFile = new File("image.jpg");
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(qrCodeImage, "jpg", imageFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try ( FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
                      OutputStream out = source.getPackagePart().getOutputStream();
                ) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
     }
}
```

So this code replaces any image with QR code.

But I have one trouble.

[Word Document after replacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJbJP.png)

So my question is?
How can I replace only the image i chose or how can i replace inserted figure with text with image generated by my own function?

Comment: Not clear what exactly your question is here. Is it about how to detect the correct image to replace? Well, you have the paragraph and the text run in which the image is in. So detect it on the position of that paragraph and/or text run. Or, if you know the name of the template picture, then detect it by name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198054/java-apache-poi-insert-an-image-infront-the-text/71202542#71202542..

Comment: Or is it about how to detect a rectangle-shape containing a special text? If so then ask this. But how to replace that found shape with a picture would be another question then and really not simple. So I would not prefer that approach.

Comment: With approach 1 i have problem because I will not know the template pictures name, so where can I read about replacing a found shape with placeholder to a picture?

Comment: As said, replacing shapes with pictures is very laborious as shapes are stored in alternate content elements (to choice shape and fallback) and so the shape needs to be changed as well as the fallback. But you have the paragraph and the text run in which the image is in. So detect it on the position or the text content of that paragraph and/or text run.

Comment: So, you are saying that it is very difficult to convert a figure with text into an image. The only way is to get the position of the figure and paste the image here, right? If yes, how to get position of the figure, else is there any possible way to choose exact image (not using image name) to replace, or when creating a word document add some property to the image?

Answer (score 1):

Detecting the picture and replacing the picture data will be the simplest. In following answer I have shown how to detect and replace pictures by name: [Java Apache POI: insert an image "infront the text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198054/java-apache-poi-insert-an-image-infront-the-text/71202542#71202542). If you do not know the name of the embedded picture, a picture also can be detected by alt text. To edit the alt text of a picture, open the context menu by right mouse click on the picture and choose **Edit A̲lt Text** from that context menu.

In [How to read alt text of image in word document apache.poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684539/how-to-read-alt-text-of-image-in-word-document-apache-poi/72690356#72690356) I have shown already how to read alt text of image.

So code could look like:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordReplacePictureData {
    
 static org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject getInlineOrAnchor(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.CTPicture ctPictureToFind, org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject inlineOrAnchor) {
  String declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace pic='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture'; ";
  org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[] selectedObjects = inlineOrAnchor.selectPath(
   declareNameSpaces 
   + "$this//pic:pic");
  for (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject selectedObject : selectedObjects) {
   if (selectedObject instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.CTPicture) {
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.CTPicture ctPicture = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.CTPicture)selectedObject;
    if (ctPictureToFind.equals(ctPicture)) {
     // this is the inlineOrAnchor for that picture   
     return inlineOrAnchor;
    }        
   }          
  }
  return null;
 }
                
 static org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject getInlineOrAnchor(XWPFRun run, XWPFPicture picture) {
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.CTPicture ctPictureToFind = picture.getCTPicture();
  for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDrawing drawing : run.getCTR().getDrawingList()) {
   for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTInline inline : drawing.getInlineList()) {
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject inlineOrAnchor = getInlineOrAnchor(ctPictureToFind, inline);
    // if inlineOrAnchor is not null, then this is the inline for that picture
    if (inlineOrAnchor != null) return inlineOrAnchor;
   }
   for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor anchor : drawing.getAnchorList()) {
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject inlineOrAnchor = getInlineOrAnchor(ctPictureToFind, anchor);
    // if inlineOrAnchor is not null, then this is the anchor for that picture
    if (inlineOrAnchor != null) return inlineOrAnchor;
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

 static org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTNonVisualDrawingProps getNonVisualDrawingProps(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject inlineOrAnchor) {
  if (inlineOrAnchor == null) return null;
  if (inlineOrAnchor instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTInline) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTInline inline = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTInline)inlineOrAnchor;
   return inline.getDocPr();    
  } else if (inlineOrAnchor instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor anchor = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor)inlineOrAnchor;
   return anchor.getDocPr();
  }
  return null;
 }

 static String getSummary(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTNonVisualDrawingProps nonVisualDrawingProps) {
  if (nonVisualDrawingProps == null) return "";
  String summary = "Id:=" + nonVisualDrawingProps.getId();
  summary += " Name:=" + nonVisualDrawingProps.getName();
  summary += " Title:=" + nonVisualDrawingProps.getTitle();
  summary += " Descr:=" + nonVisualDrawingProps.getDescr();
  return summary;
 }
    
 static XWPFPicture getPictureByAltText(XWPFRun run, String altText) {
  if (altText == null) return null;
  for (XWPFPicture picture : run.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
   String altTextSummary = getSummary(getNonVisualDrawingProps(getInlineOrAnchor(run, picture)));
   System.out.println(altTextSummary);
   if (altTextSummary.contains(altText)) {
    return picture;   
   }
  }
  return null;
 }
 
 static void replacePictureData(XWPFPictureData source, String pictureResultPath) {
  try ( FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(pictureResultPath); 
        OutputStream out = source.getPackagePart().getOutputStream();
       ) {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
   int length;
   while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();  
  }
 }
 
 static void replacePicture(XWPFRun run, String altText, String pictureResultPath) {
  XWPFPicture picture = getPictureByAltText(run, altText);
  if (picture != null) {
   XWPFPictureData source = picture.getPictureData();
   replacePictureData(source, pictureResultPath);
  }   
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String templatePath = "./source.docx";
  String resultPath = "./result.docx";
  String altText = "Placeholder QR-Code";
  String pictureResultPath = "./QR.jpg";
  
  try ( XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(templatePath));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resultPath);
       ) {
   
   for (IBodyElement bodyElement : document.getBodyElements()) {
    if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
     XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
     for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
      replacePicture(run, altText, pictureResultPath);
     }
    }
   }       
   document.write(out);
  }    
 }
}
```

This replaces the picture or pictures having alt text "Placeholder QR-Code". All other pictures remain as they are.

Replacing shapes with pictures is very laborious as shapes are stored in alternate content elements (to choice shape and fallback) and so the shape needs to be changed as well as the fallback. If one would let the fallback untouched, then applications which rely on that fallback will further show the old shape. Furthermore detecting shapes by text box content is not really much simpler than detecting pictures by alt text content.

Comment: in getInlineOrAnchor function i have error with calling it again with arguments getInlineOrAnchor(ctPictureToFind, anchor), because first one is not run, second is not picture?

Comment: @Alga Qazaqstan: Cannot reproducing that issue. My code is complete. It is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.2` without errors. So what exact error do you get using what version of Apache POI?

Comment: yes, my version is 5.0.0, so i will update and try again

Comment: @Alga Qazaqstan: Works for me using `apache poi 5.0.0` too. What **exact** error you get?

Comment: sorry, it was only my fault, typo((

Comment: what if i only have a placeholder like ${qr:size} how can i replace that text with a qr image generated by my other function and set its top left corner to the start of the text?